# ¿Cómo mantener los estilos de bootstrap en el paginador en Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-8

Usualmente uso datatables y la paginación me parece automáticamente y con sus respectivo estilos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero hoy estoy tratando de poner los links de paginación manualmente {{$task->links() }} pero me aparecen sin los estilos de bootstrap:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tratado de encerrar los links en un ul con las clases pagination pero siguen sin aparecerme los estilos:

```
<div class="pagination pagination-sm">
    {{ $tasks->links() }}
</div>
```

Comment: Aqui tienes la respuesta: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#using-bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como puedes observar en las *release notes*, [Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#tailwind-pagination-views) ahora usa por *default* el framework **Tailwind** para los estilos de la paginación.

Así que si requieres seguir aplicando Bootstrap para dicha tarea, te diriges al *AppServiceProvider* en: `tuApp/app/providers/AppServiceProvider` y en el método [`boot()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#using-bootstrap) colocas lo siguiente:

```
Paginator::useBootstrap();
```

No olvides importar por su namespace al *Paginator* así:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
```